# asp.net url rewriting intelligencia exclude scriptresource.axd

Tags: asp.net, regex, url-rewriting, web-config

I am using intelligencia.urlrewriter to handle my url routing.
I'm using asp.net and the issue has arose where the ScriptResource.axd file is being rewritten, so I need to add an exclusion to my rule, but can't figure it out.

Here's my rule:

```
<rewrite url="/pages/(.+)" to="/routed_pages/Page.aspx?slug=$1" />
```

With this rule, the ScriptResource.axd is being rewritten to /pages/ScriptResource.axd and causing errors.

Here is the support page: http://urlrewriter.net/index.php/support

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I recently used IIS url rewrite module 2.0 where we can ignore url like below, may be you can get an idea from here, it will be somewhat similar.
<conditions>
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="(\.css|\.js|\.jpg|\.png|\.woff|\.tiff|\.gif|\.dev|\.swf)$" negate="true" />
</conditions>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was finally able to accomplish by doing this:

```
<rewrite url="^(/.+(\.axd)(\?.+)?)$" to="$1" processing="stop" />
<rewrite url="/pages/(.+)" to="/routed_pages/Page.aspx?slug=$1" />
```